# Safely retrieving a value from a route

Tags: javascript, angular, url-routing

In my Angular application I have updated some URLs in my project from previously using query string elements like this:

`http://www.whatever.com/products?productName=TheMainProduct&id=234234`

to a route based system similar to this:

`http://www.whatever.com/products/TheMainProduct/234234`

This works fine but most of the time except when there's a product called something like The / Next / Big Thing

So the slashes break the routing as is expected. I've encoded the product name using encodeUrlComponent and was going to decode using decodeUrlComponent but I was curious as to whether this is considered safe. The values are going to be the same as when they were query string elements and that was considered safe, so is decodeUrlComponent ok to use here or should I add an extra layer of protection against malicious angles?

I've read differing reports on whether decodeUrlComponent is good practice so am looking for some clarity or alternatives if it's a bad idea.

Why do I need to decode it? Well I'm navigating to a component and using the product name, taken from the URL to populate some data on the component I navigate to. So for example a form field will have the product name pre-populated in it as it was taken from the URL.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to decode it ? If you are using Angular then you should have a state to keep record of the product. So why can't you get reference to the product name from the state ? Then use `new URL('The / Next / Big Thing', base_url)` to get a valid url for the product just to add to the routing ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by state in this instance. My application is currently stateless, I don't use NgRx or any other state solution. I think you're right though, I haven't properly described why I need to decode it, I'll update the question.

Comment: So you don't have at least a `behaviorsubject` ? How do you render the product page without store your product data at least in a variable ?

Comment: I do use BehaviourSubjects elsewhere in the app but not for state management. In this instance I'm taking the URL route parameter and populating a form field on the page with the value.

Comment: Oh. then I think best solution here is to use `URL` object to create a url and decode it using `decodeUrlComponent` as you mentioned. If I have access to the backend code, I would validate the title on the server and add constraint to the database to prevent unwanted characters on the title. If I don't have access to the backend, then encoding and decoding is the only solution for me.

Comment: Check this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-decode-uri-component

Comment: Can you make your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original Comment**

> Oh. then I think best solution here is to use URL object to create a
> url and decode it using decodeUrlComponent as you mentioned. If I have
> access to the backend code, I would validate the title on the server
> and add constraint to the database to prevent unwanted characters on
> the title. If I don't have access to the backend, then encoding and
> decoding is the only solution for me

In this scenario I would use JavaScript's `URL` object to create an encoded url from the title of the product.

```
const product_url = new URL('The / Next / Big Thing', 'http://www.whatever.com/products')
```

This will return an encoded URL for use in the Angular router.

When its comes to malicious code, what I would do is prevent inserting them in to the database. That mean, whenever the product is creating, check for suspicious characters like, `<`, `/>` etc on the server and prevent them from inserting.

I would suggest you to use this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-decode-uri-component), This decodes strings that were encoded by `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`, without throwing errors on invalid escapes